# How to do webservice autherization in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, oauth, authorization

I only have Base URL, Consumer Key and Consumer Secrete. Here i want to connect it with the server to get json response for my iphone app.

I tried many ways to connect it but all tries got failure in objective c.

code which i used in Objective c

```
AFOAuth2Client *client = [AFOAuth2Client clientWithBaseURL:url   clientID:@"----------------------------" secret:@"------------------------------"];

[client authenticateUsingOAuthWithURLString:@"/sources"
                                 parameters:nil
                                success:^(AFOAuthCredential *credential) {
                                    NSLog(@"Success");
                                }failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                    NSLog(@"Error = %@",error);
                                }];
```

If i used Same Base URL, Consumer Key and Consumer Secrete in PHP then it succeeded

code which i used in php is

```
    $key = '-------------------------'; 
    $secret = '----------------------------'; 
    $options = array( 'consumer_key' => $key, 'consumer_secret' => $secret );
    OAuthStore::instance("2Leg", $options );
    $url = "http://api.seatseller.travel/sources";
    $method = "GET";
    $params = null;

    $request = new OAuthRequester($url, $method, $params);
    $result = $request->doRequest();
    //echo $result['body'];
    $links = json_decode($result['body'], TRUE);
```

So i want to know what will be the correct procedure to do this in objective c for iphone app

Comment: Show the objective c, not some code in a different language that works...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this.

```
// Setup NSURLConnection
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                 timeoutInterval:30.0];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];

// NSURLConnection Delegates
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"USER"
                                                                password:@"PASSWORD"
                                                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        NSLog(@"credential created");
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");    
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"previous authentication failure");
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    ...
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    ...
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    ...
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    ...
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How to use Consumer key and secrete while requesting

Comment: instead of username and password may be you can pass consumer key and secret. I m not sure about it. This code works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AFNetworking`.
If you only want upload text, you can use `GET` method, it is very sample!

```
-(void)uploadtexttosever{

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

I am use AFNetworking very good.
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: How to use Consumer key and secrete while requesting

Comment: I don't know about your code.
But if you want connect to the server and get Json response, you should use AFNetworking library.
It is very sample.

Comment: I have added objective c code which i have tried in question. Please check it

Comment: Yes! I had seen your code.
Becase, I do not understand about AFOAuth2Client library, But I know about AFNetworking library.
I think you should use AFNetworking if you want get Json response from server.
If you want use AFNetworking, I will instruct for you.
AFNetworking is very popular with everybody